# Find a table row number using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I've got a table and need to find a specific row number. In this case, I'm interested in the 2nd row (2nd tr).

Here's the HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="classes mico_models_classes_7 listRowWhite">
      <tr class="classes mico_models_classes_8 listRowDark">
         <td style="width:130px;">9:00am - 10:30am</td>
         <td class="noprint enrolledFull" style="width:70px;height:40px;text-align:center;">   </td>
         <td style="width:200px;">
         <a class="eventName" data-eventdescription="Very long spin class" data-eventname="Spinning 90 min" href="javascript://">Spinning 90 min</a>
        <br>
       with
       <a class="classesEmployeeName" title="John Doe" href="javascript://" data-employeeid="5117">John Doe</a>
      </td>
    <td style="text-align:right;width:72px;">0 of 20</td>
   <td>Spin Class</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="classes mico_models_classes_9 listRowWhite">
  <tr class="classes mico_models_classes_10 listRowDark">
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, the following returns null for `dataRowIndex`:

```
String classTittle = "Spinning 90 min";
String dataRowIndex = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-eventname='" + classTitle + "']")).getAttribute("rowIndex");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by iterating the tr HTML-elements while counting them. You can also access them while iterating.

```
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr"));

        int row = 0;

        for( WebElement w : element){

            String elemText = w.getText();

            System.out.println(elemText);

            String clickText = "Spinning 90 min";

            if(elemText.contains(clickText)){

                w.click(); //do something with the element

                System.out.println("Text in row " + row + " is " + clickText + " so i clicked it!");
            }

            System.out.println("this was row " + row + "\n");

            row++;
        }
```

Will yield:

```
this was row 0

9:00am - 10:30am Spinning 90 min
with John Doe 0 of 20 Spin Class
Text in row 1 is Spinning 90 min so i clicked it!
this was row 1


this was row 2


this was row 3
```

You might want to encapsulate your specific logic in a method later on. Hope this helps ^^-d

Comment: I was assuming that the findelement would work and could avoid the iteration, but I couldn't get it to work.Your iteration worked perfectly, thanks for that!